# Windows registry keys that affect shortcuts behavior

Tags: windows, windows-registry, shortcuts

I want to ask if someone has an info about windows registry key `HKCR\lnkfile`. As I've found out it describes how shortcuts have to do their work but cannot manage to find much info, all I know, that if this key is removed then shortcuts in windows machine do not working. So want to ask if someone knows something about that key, its subkeys and values.

Comment: Are you looking for the original values or just how those values work?

Comment: @Mario I'm looking how that values work, I know originals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most basics regarding these keys can be found in [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690196(v=vs.85).aspx).

Under Windows 8 there are a few sub keys and values:

- The **default value** usually defines the visible file type name, but here it is ignored (see **FriendlyTypeName**).
- **Clsid** (key) defines the [CLSID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691424(v=vs.85).aspx) associated with shortcuts.
- **EditFlags** (value) is a bitmask using the [FILETYPEATTRIBUTEFLAGS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762506(v=vs.85).aspx).
- **FriendlyTypeName** (value) is simply a linked string ressource identifying the file (overwriting the default value).
- **IsShortcut** (value) is a hint for Explorer and common dialog controls to show the shortcut arrow in the corner of the file icon. The value doesn't matter, the existance of the value is enough.
- **NeverShowExt** (value) is another hint and does exactly what the name implies.
- **ShellEx** (key) defines additional handlers (CLSIDs in keys):

  - **ContextMenuHandlers** defines additional entries in the files' context menu like "Open containing folder" (not sure about the exact wording).
  - **DropHandler** defines additional entries in the drag & drop menu (drag a shortcut to another folder using the right mouse button).
  - **IconHandler** overwrites the file type's default icon. This essentially defines the CLSID being responsible to pick the proper icon.
  - **PropertySheetHandlers** add additional tabs to the file properties. In this case it's the "Shortcut" tab.
- **tabsets** (key) I'm not really sure about this one, but I assume it defines the file type specific ribbon to be shown in Windows 8.

The default CLSID for shortcuts is **{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}**, which can be found under **HKCR\CLSID\{00021401-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}**. This key essentially controls the library file containing the code to handle the file type (e.g. double clicking/the **open** verb), which is **Shell32.dll**.

Comment: Is there any way to force the keyboard shortcuts to work when working fullscreen.  Windows turned this off a while ago, can it be re-enabled?

Comment: @ggb667 This was about file shortcuts, not keyboard shortcuts. If shortcuts for a program aren't working globally, you might have to run it as administrator/with elevated privileges.